# Help with LDRD Instruction

Tags: ida, disassembly, arm

According to documentation, the LDRD instruction works, as follows

```
LDRD    R8, R9, [R3, #0x20];  load r8 from a word 32 bytes above the address in R3, and load r9 from  a word 36 bytes above the address in R3
```

I understand the first part, R8 loads from a word 32 bytes(0x20) above R3. Its the second part I don't understand. Why is it 36 bytes instead of 32?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please referr to the actual [instruction manual](https://www.scss.tcd.ie/~waldroj/3d1/arm_arm.pdf).

from page A4-50:

> LDRD (Load Registers Doubleword) loads a pair of ARM registers from two consecutive words of memory.
>   The pair of registers is restricted to being an even-numbered register and the odd-numbered register that
>   immediately follows it (for example, R10 and R11).

tl/dr: 36 is 32 + 4 (it loads to concecutive words)
basically it says at offset 0x20 to r3, get two words for r8 and r9.